# .htacces rewrite rule for subdomain like project1, project2 e.t.c

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have many rules in my .htaccess file.

```
# project1.mysite.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} project1.mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/project1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project1/$1 [L]

# project554.mysite.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} project554.mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/project554
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project554/$1 [L]

# project44.mysite.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} project44.mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/project44
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project44/$1 [L]
```

e.t.c

i think what there is more smart rule by using only one mask.
subdomain like `project{number}` -> to folder like `/project{number}`

please advise a good solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (project\d+).mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/%1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

This should work as expected. Remove everything else from the file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! One more small question: how to show 404 error if folder doesn't exist? Right now it call server error. (in case if user type "somenotexist.mysite.com") ErrorDocument 404 /404/ doesn't help.